# File manager is not allowed to do anything

Tags: filemanager

I am new to ubuntu. I noticed that the file manager is basically useless. I tried to remove a folder inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs` but nothing happens after selecting the folder and pressing the button `del`.

On windows I could just delete it by using the windows explorer.

Is ubuntu only designed for terminal usage?

Comment: A webserver should be part of a server setup, not a desktop. A desktop is a loss of performance you do not want to be taken away from your webserver. "Is ubuntu only designed for terminal usage?" Why are you dissing the BEST feature ever in any OS?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by starting nautilus as sudo.
First I had to install the package `gksu`:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then I started nautilus like this:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Comment: Be careful when using sudo nautilus , you don't want to use it any more then you have to since it can open you up to vulnerabilities. sudo and command in terminal are much better but for learning purposes I can see the benefits of learning through graphical first then terminal but the better you get at terminal the more you will understand about operating systems them selves. And most importantly remote ssh is so much fun after knowing what your doing :)

Comment: Yes I know how to use terminal, but it takes longer

Comment: Cheers :) to bad there is no points for solving your own question haha

Comment: Yes :( It says "You can't vote for your own post" :(((((( lol

Answer (score 1):

Is Ubuntu only designed for terminal usage?

NO. You could open file manager and press del.

inside file manager right click a file/folder see properties see permissions.. if you’re not the owner of the file/folder you cant do various things with it see [Lubuntu file permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeQ7C.jpg).

same thing using terminal

```
<open.terminal>
sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp/htdocs/<folder.or.file.to.delete>
<enter.root.password.at.prompt>
```

or use mc

```
<open.terminal>
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mc
sudo mc
<navigate.to.your.file.folder>
<select.it.and.press.F8.to.delete.it>
```

or you can run file manager as root.. same procedure as mc

inside Linux most of the files don’t belong to user.you(as in windows) so you you cant do various jobs on them, see

- [File permissions and attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Permissions_and_Attributes)
- [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions)